# ESP32 full wifi mesh

Tags: network-programming, wifi, esp32, mesh-network

We have been trying to build a full wifi mesh using ESP32 and/or ESP8266. Looking at the resources available online, we could only find 'painless mesh' which we found to be a partial mesh. For bigger networks, this topology might create delays in data transfer.

Any resources available for full mesh? We are open to change hardware too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espressif has built a [mesh network library](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/mesh.html) which is used by the same "painless mesh". Espressif doesn´t offer other mesh options and the WiFi drivers are closed-source, so that's pretty much it, I suspect.